# Android Espresso : cannot resolve symbol AndroidJUnit4.class

Tags: android, unit-testing, user-interface, android-espresso

I'm trying to create Espresso UI test inside the new Android project but I faced with the following problem.

If I tried to create a empty test class:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;


@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class LoginActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginActivity> {

}
```

I always get this error message:

```
cannot resolve symbol AndroidJUnit4.class
```

And almost all imported libraries are marked as unused.

build.gradle file is containing the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.some.thing.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.11'
    // App dependencies
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'
    // TESTING DEPENDENCIES
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    // Set this dependency to build and run Espresso tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
    // add this for intent mocking support
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2'
    // add this for webview testing support
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2'
    // Set this dependency to build and run UI Automator tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2'
}
```

If I put these setting on my other test project it works, so I don't know what can be wrong?

I've followed this tutorial:"

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTestingEspresso/article.html

And I've tried to resolve it by following SO question:
[Cannot resolve symbol 'AndroidJUnit4'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603487/cannot-resolve-symbol-androidjunit4)

But without the luck.

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: android { 
testBuildType "debug"
} worked for me like a charm.

Answer (score 14):

I've tried the same tutorial from vogella too and ran into many issues. One of the first issues I ran into was a dependency clash between the annotation versions of v23 libs and the Espresso libs.

Then I found another recently updated tutorial from Roger Hu "[UI Testting with Espresso](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/UI-Testing-with-Espresso)". I noticed a remark that Espresso is not supporting Marshmallow yet.

The dependencies were added as follows:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2') {
    // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since Espresso
    // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
    // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since the test runner
    // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

This solved my dependency conflict and I didn't see any of the rest of the issues occurring.

Comment: You're a life saver. Just to be clear to others, just use the depencies above. Nothing else. Otherwise you'll still get the dependency clash.

Answer (score 11):

I solved it by manually importing the following, I thought it should be imported automatically but it didn't :

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
```

Answer (score 8):

The reason you get that error message may be because your folder where the test is residing is not matching the spec.  The folder must be **src/androidTest/java**.

**[Take a look at this article](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html)** which says...

> Run Instrumented Unit Tests To run your instrumented tests, follow
>   these steps:
>
> Be sure your project is synchronized with Gradle by clicking Sync
>   Project  in the toolbar. Run your test in one of the following ways:
>   To run a single test, open the Project window, and then right-click a
>   test and click Run . To test all methods in a class, right-click a
>   class or method in the test file and click Run . To run all tests in a
>   directory, right-click on the directory and select Run tests . The
>   Android Plugin for Gradle compiles the instrumented test code located
>   in the default directory (src/androidTest/java/), builds a test APK
>   and production APK, installs both APKs on the connected device or
>   emulator, and runs the tests. Android Studio then displays the results
>   of the instrumented test execution in the Run window.

Therefore folks,  for **instrumentation test the folder must be (do not forget the case)**

> src/androidTest/java

and for **local tests the folder must be**

> src/test/java

You can then have your package folder(s) to match your app package

Hope, this helps for the community!

Comment: This error occurs in other cases as well though, such as conflicting versioning of test/prod dependencies.

Comment: Was the folder androidTest all the time! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I solved it using change the constant

```
minSdkVersion
```

to version 18 in the **build.gradle** file.

Following gradle.file is working:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.something.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.11'

    // TESTING DEPENDENCIES
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    // Set this dependency to build and run Espresso tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
    // add this for intent mocking support
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2'
    // add this for webview testing support
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2'
    // Set this dependency to build and run UI Automator tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2'
}
```

Comment: Changing sdk version solved it for me too, but the funny thing is after it worked once, I set it back to 19 and it still works!

Comment: This can work but I don't highly recommend this solution. As for instance, I am struggling beggar and with this solution I would lost a sizable portion of the marketshare. :/

Answer (score 5):

As per the above gradle changes given:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
```

you need to change to

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

and for me it wasn't working even with above change, so what I noticed was I was missing the below inclusion:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
```

and it worked fine for me.

The complete build.gradle can be found as below:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    lintOptions {
        // IMPORTANT: We are disabling this rule to avoid build errors on PrettyTime. Although
        //pretty time references an InvalidPackage it does not do it in the code sections we use
        //given how easy this library is to use I would prefer not to replace it with something
        //like Joda-Time which is overkill for such a small section of the app.
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.test.dialer"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 15
        versionName "0.6.15."
        renderscriptTargetApi 22
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        production {
            storeFile file("keystore.jks")
            storePassword "hello"
            keyAlias "production"
            keyPassword "android"
        }

        debug {
            storeFile file("keystore.jks")
            storePassword "hello"
            keyAlias "debug"
            keyPassword "android"
        }

    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.production
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

        internal_test {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix ".test"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.8.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:3.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
    compile 'squizbit.com.jsonobjectified:jetjson:1.0.3@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'

    releaseCompile 'co.test.dialersdk:dialersdk:1.0.8@aar';
    debugCompile 'co.test.dialersdk:dialersdk-debug:1.0.8@aar';    
    internal_testCompile 'co.test.dialersdk:dialersdk-internal_test:1.0.8@aar';

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:rules:0.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'


}
```

Hope this will surely help someone as I have struggled for half a day to fix it even after following complete steps of vogella tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you may have multiple Build types, Default Android Project create two build type (debug/release), change build variant to debug or set the value as below

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing

```
Currently only one Build Type is tested. By default it is the debug Build Type, but this can be reconfigured with:
android {
    ...
    testBuildType "staging"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I resolved changing my Build Variant. I was running the test in the release build.

[When I changed to "debug", it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhWgr.png)

Comment: Oh wow I just spent an hour trying to fix my dependencies and what not! Intellij should give better feedback in this case than "class not found".

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603487/cannot-resolve-symbol-androidjunit4).

"I made the mistake to put the test classes at src/test. After moving them to src/androidTest/java/... the dependency was resolved. Maybe this is your problem too."