# Unit tests with new Android X

Tags: android, testing, junit

I've tried to use new android x and create some unit test. But i can't find new test runner for it. 
I've tried:

```
androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha1.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

and  get

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
```

What i should do?

Comment: Have you looked at other questions that address this same error? For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087004/androidjunit4-test-not-found, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553155/android-studio-integration-test-cannot-resolve-symbol-androidjunit4?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603487/cannot-resolve-symbol-androidjunit4. I don't think any of these are using the new `androidx` namespace, but they might still solve your problem.