# Cannot resolve symbol 'test' in Android Support library

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-support-library

I'm just starting to play around with Android and I'm having trouble with some androidTest examples that I've come across. Basically, I get a **Cannot resolve symbol 'test'** error message from Android Studio in the import statements for the InstrumentationRegistry and AndroidJUnit4 classes of my instrumented test file:

**ExampleInstrumentedTest.java**

```
package com.example.androidtestexample;

import android.content.Context;

import android.support.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    public void useAppContext() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();

        assertEquals("com.example.androidtestexample", appContext.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

As a consequence, the AndroidJUnit4 symbol of the `@RunWith` statement can't be resolved either and when I try to run the instrumentation test I get an 'Edit configuration' window with an 'Instrumentation runner class not specified' error.

I'm using Android Studio 3.5.3, but this example uses 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'. The app gradle.build is as follows (I had to add the `aaptOptions` statements as suggested [here](https://www.solutionfactory.in/posts/java-util-concurrent-ExecutionException-com-android-ide-common-process-ProcessException) to get the minimum reproducible example working):

**build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.androidtestexample"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}
```

As suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603487/cannot-resolve-symbol-androidjunit4), I have double-checked that the debug build variant was selected and that the instrumentation test source file was in the **src/androidTest/java/** folder.

I understand that this example is quite outdated and, from another of the answers to the aforementioned question and from [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/package-summary), that the `android.support.test` package is deprecated and AndroidX should be used instead. However, from [this page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library) I also understand that it should still be possible to use the Android Support library for historical artifacts, hence my question:

Is there a way for me to fix this problem and run such old examples with the `android.support.test` package without needing to migrate them to AndroidX?